# If $f$ is invertible show the normed function has no maximum

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n, f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ continuously differentiable so that $Df(x)$ is invertible for all $x\in U.$ I need to show that the function $k: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $k(x):=\|f(x)\|_2$ has no maximum.

Since $Df(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in U,$ its determinant is nowhere vanishing meaning that the gradients along all directions can not vanish, which is a necessary condition of an extremum for $f$. Is this correct ? At the other hand the function in question here is not $f$ rather its norm. We also know that $f$ and also its norm is continuous. But $U$ is open. I am wondering if one can use the result according to which only on a closed set one can then draw a conclusion that a function will take its extreme values.

Can somebody provide some more insight or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: $f$ cannot have an extremum because $f$ is a vector valued function, and there is no natural ordering on vectors. In addition $k$ may not be differentiable. Hint- in a Hilbert space, if you want to do something with $\|\cdot\|_2$, you should probably use $\|\cdot\|_2^2$ instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to know is that the image $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$. This follows from the inverse function theorem: For each $x \in U$ there exists an open $U_x$ such that $x \in U_x \subset U$ and $f$ maps $U_x$ diffeomorphically onto an open neigborhood of $f(x)$.

So let $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ be open. Assume there exists $y \in V$ such that
$$\lVert z \rVert \le \lVert y \rVert \text{ for all } z \in V .\tag{1} $$
Since $V$ is open, there exists $r > 0$ such that the open ball $B_r(y) = \{ z \in \mathbb R^n \mid \lVert z - y \rVert < r\}$ is contained in $V$.

Case 1. $\lVert y \rVert = 0$. Then $y = 0$ and $(1)$ contradicts $B_r(0) \subset V$.

Case 2. $\lVert y \rVert \ne 0$. Let $z = (1+\frac{r}{2\lVert y \rVert})y$. Then $\lVert z \rVert = \lVert y \rVert + \frac{r}{2} > \lVert y \rVert$ and $\lVert z - y \rVert = \frac{r}{2}$, i.e. $z \in B_r(y) \subset V$ which contradicts $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks.I do not get it quite clearly if $V$ is a subset of the image of $f$.

Comment: @user996159 Take $V = f(U)$ which is open. I showed that $V$ has no element $y$ such that $\lVert y \rVert$ is maximal.